# Things to know when writing a web app hosted in a load-balanced server?

Tags: php, web-applications, load, webserver

Let's say your writing a PHP application that will be hosted in a load-balanced/multi-server setup. What are the things you need to know in order to ensure smooth operation? Right now the only thing I think will be an issue is PHP sessions (i.e., you must use a custom database handler for it). Anything else?

Comment: While I ofcourse concur with the session being a point of investigation, I do not think a DB handler is the only (or even a good) solution: You are turning the session DB into a new, un-balanced bottleneck. Handling session stickyness at the load balancer or something distributed (like e.g. memcached) seems more obvious to me: If you lose a server, you lose a few sessions - this should be more acceptable than a centralized session DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's turn this into an answer:

In my experience, the overwhelming majority of PHP applications is not or not only constrained by PHP horsepower on the webserver, but at least as much by backing store, i.e. Database and/or files.

So load balancing a PHP application without carefull analysis bears the potential to make things worse: Hit the weakest link in the chain with more and more load.

So the first - and IMHO most important "thing to know when writing a web app hosted in a load-balanced server" is the load pattern, and its potential for balancing. If your app performs bad, you load-balance it on more servers, then find out you now have more servers waiting for the DB, you are in trouble.

Here is an out-of-the blue checklist, please reagrd it as a brainstorm (or a brainfart) only:

- First: Are you really CPU-bound?
- Which pages are hit most (see your log)
- For the top N of these (with a suitable N) check the processing pattern: Where do the CPU cycles go?
- What would be the side effects of making sessions, uploads, file storage (add whatever you use) shared and would it be offset by the load balancing?

Comments welcome, I am very sure to have not even scratched the surface!

**Edit**

Just thought of something that bit me once in this context: Resource locking. Brace yourself for a higher degree of concurrency, if you go multi-server

Comment: I've noticed a main reason for load-balancing (especially in the Windows world) is for high-availability, not performance, since LB handles downed servers (namely for Patch Tuesday updates which can introduce up to an hours' downtime). This is repeated in the DB servers (except they tend to be failover-only, rather than load-balanced).

Comment: @David Thanls for your input. If we are talking of this kind HA, we are not talking of a real LB scenario, but of a sort of failover. Failover for planned downtime could be handled as part of the downtime  (e.g. pathing) procedures, so the need for e.g. sessions would be greatly reduced: Let the LB handle session stickyness and instruct it to hand new sessions off to the other (already patched) server, then wait for sessions to end.

Answer (score 1):

File uploads/downloads could be also an issue - you probably would need them to be visible all servers

Comment: This issue can be eliminated by having the load-balanced webservers to be "code only, no data". Things like downloads and content images would be stored directly in the database or some kind of shared storage like a SAN.